# make a live tiles from binary clock? WP7

Tags: windows-phone-7, live-tile

A couple of day's ago I made a binary clock app.
It works like this.

Every time a dispacthertimer ticks it updates some image from one source to another.

So I been reading about making your own tiles and found something called ree7 that sounds like what im looking for.

But everywhere I read about a question like this, people said that it can't be done.
So does anyone know if it's possible?

Sorry for my bad spelling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The smallest intervals are one hour for `ShellTileScheduler` and 30 minutes for `PeriodicAgent`, so I'm pretty sure that's not enough for a tile, that could look like a clock.

Comment: arhh okay. what about the facebook app? changing profilpic of freinds?

Comment: I have WP7 phone and don't see any pictures on facebook tile :) And the people hub - that's a feature build into system. You can't do the same with your app.

Comment: ohh it's was people hub, but damn, would be nice to have live animede tiles